# How to get bpy.data.is_dirty updating when changes are done by script?

Tags: python

My addon relies on checking `bpy.data.is_dirty`. This seems to work fine in interactive mode, however when I tried adding automated tests for my addon I have faced issue with `bpy.data.is_dirty` not updating correctly when things are getting changed from my tests (Python script).

Example script to reproduce (on Blender 2.79):

```
>>> bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_start = bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_start + 1
>>> bpy.data.is_dirty
False
```

I can see starting frame change on the timeline, however there is no asterisk "*" visible in title (which generally indicates unsaved changes).
If I change starting frame by clicking on small arrow by number it marks the file correctly as changed (both the asterisk appears and `bpy.data.is_dirty` returns `True).

I have also managed to get a state in tests that have `bpy.data.is_dirty` returns `True` even on the next line just after call to `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()`.

Is there some function I need to call to get Blender's internal state to update `bpy.data.is_dirty`?

Alternatively, as I need it only for tests, is there some way to make sure that `bpy.data.is_dirty` is in a desired state? (i.e. I need to be able to set it both to `True` and `False` depending on scenario)

I read https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/info_gotcha.html#no-updates-after-setting-values and tried using `bpy.context.scene.update()`, but it doesn't seem to impact `bpy.data.is_dirty`.

Comment: There are many problems with "bpy.data" updates, I suggest you report this